# Parameters for objective function of fmin_cobyla of Python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am using fmin_cobyla for to solve a constraint optimization problem. my objective function has two parameters in the form of array and I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
from scipy.optimize import fmin_cobyla

def distance (x,Weight,Initial):
    dist = Weight*(Initial-x)**2
    return np.sum(dist)


Weight =np.array([10, 10, 10, 10])
Initial=np.array([1.  ,  1.4 ,  0.95,  1.2])

A = np.array([(1, -1,0,0), (0,1,-1,0), (0,0,1,-1)])            
b = np.array([0,0,0])
constraints = []
for i in range(len(A)):
    def f(x, i = i):        
        return np.dot(x,A[i])-b[i]
    constraints.append(f)

res1 = fmin_cobyla(distance, Initial, constraints,args=(Weight,Initial), rhoend = 1e-7)
```

I ma using args=(Weight,Initial) to pass parameters to the objective function which is "distance" however I got the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-fc267b7a75d8> in <module>()
     20     constraints.append(f)
     21 
---> 22 res1 = fmin_cobyla(distance, Initial, constraints,args=(Weight,Initial), rhoend = 1e-7)

C:\Users\ameimand\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\cobyla.py in fmin_cobyla(func, x0, cons, args, consargs, rhobeg, rhoend, iprint, maxfun, disp, catol)
    170 
    171     sol = _minimize_cobyla(func, x0, args, constraints=con,
--> 172                            **opts)
    173     if iprint > 0 and not sol['success']:
    174         print("COBYLA failed to find a solution: %s" % (sol.message,))

C:\Users\ameimand\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\cobyla.py in _minimize_cobyla(fun, x0, args, constraints, rhobeg, tol, iprint, maxiter, disp, catol, **unknown_options)
    237     cons_lengths = []
    238     for c in constraints:
--> 239         f = c['fun'](x0, *c['args'])
    240         try:
    241             cons_length = len(f)

TypeError: f() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

It seems the error is related to passing parameters to the constraint while args() is supposed to pass them to objective function.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_cobyla.html#scipy.optimize.fmin_cobyla) say:

> consargs : tuple, optional
>
> Extra arguments to pass to constraint functions (**default of None means use same extra arguments as those passed to func**). Use () for no extra arguments.

(annotation by me)

So in your case `args=(Weight,Initial)` will be passed to `f`.

Add the argument `consargs=()` like:

```
res1 = fmin_cobyla(distance, Initial, constraints,args=(Weight,Initial),
               consargs=(), rhoend = 1e-7)
```

This will make the code run. But i did not analyze anything else!

(Usually people use the more general [minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize) instead of the more low-level functions like [fmin_cobyla](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_cobyla.html#scipy.optimize.fmin_cobyla))